# angularjs ng-include not showing file

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, angularjs-ng-include

I'm trying to implement a basic node-express angular app which includes an ng-include directive.

This is the structure of my app:

- App:

  - server.js
  - package.json
  - public:

    - js
    - css
    - index.html
    - partials:

      - header.html
      - partial-about.html
      - partial-homt.html

The content of my server.js is the following:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.configure(function () {
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public")); 
    app.use(express.logger("dev"));
});

app.listen(port);
console.log("App listening on port: " + port);
```

This is the content of my index.html:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>AngularJS UIRouter demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.8/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="MyApp">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">DD test Angular-UI Router</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="./partials/partial-home.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="./partials/partial-about.html">About</a></li>          
    </ul>
    </nav>

    <div ui-view></div>

</body>
</html>
```

However when I try to simplify index.html to this:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>AngularJS UIRouter demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.8/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-include="'./partials/header.html'" ></div>
    <div ui-view></div>

</body>
</html>
```

With header.html obviously including:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">DD test Angular-UI Router</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="./partials/partial-home.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="./partials/partial-about.html">About</a></li>          
    </ul>
</nav>
```

It doesn't work, any ideas?

Comment: I think the ng-include path should be `'/partials/header.html'`

Comment: @Chandermani I tried that too, it didn't work, it returns me a blank page. In the developer console, I can actually see <div ng-include="'/partials/header.html'" ></div> instead of its content.

Comment: @Bondifrench: In the DevTools `Network` tab you should see the request related to the `ngInclude`. What do yoh see there ? Is there a request at all ? What is thd status code ? What is the URL ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem Had a look, there is no request to the file mentionned in ng-include, there are request to boostrap, angular and the likes, but not even to index.html actually. Edit: sorry last comment was stupid as I can see the index.html in the Elements part of DevTools

Comment: @Bondifrench: Are you sure `MyApp` is spelled and cased correctly in both cases ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem Sorry, I am a bit confused, for the moment MyApp is only present once, in index.html in the body tag. As for the moment I don't have any controllers, it's not used in any other file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for Angular to take over (and on order for the directives to become effective), you need to initialize the module:

```
<head>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript">
        angular.module('MyApp', ['ui.router']);
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I actually found out, as currently i'm not using anything from the ui-router that I just need to create a script which includes angular.module('MyApp',[]);